# 401 error message on post request solution?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman, http-status-code-401

im trying to make a post request using postman to my api endpoint  http://localhost:5000/api/cart  to check if adding to a user cart is working properly this tis the structure

```
const Cart = require('../models/cart');

// Create a new cart for the logged-in user



router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.user || !req.user.id) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
    }

    const newCart = new Cart({
      user: req.user.id,
      items: req.body.items,
    });

    await newCart.save();
    res.status(201).json(newCart);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server Error' });
  }
}
```

this is my server.js

```
const cartRoute = require('./routes/carts');
app.use('/api/cart', cartRoute);
```

this is my model structure

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  items: [
    {
      product: { type: String, required: true },
      quantity: { type: Number, required: true, default: 1 },
      price: { type: Number, required: true }
    }
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);
```

and this is the JSON body when i make the request

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "product": "<product_name>",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 100.00
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried to define a KEY and VALUE in HEADERS in postman KEY: Authorization and VALUE: Bearer <token> (token provided when a users logs in when I make a post request on a endpoint that I previously defined in

```
  http://localhost:5000/api/users/login
```

)

also I have tried to make a fnction to check if users is authorized

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Forbidden' });
    }
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
}
```

then calling it in between

```
app.use('/api/cart',authenticateToken, cartRoute);
```

No matter what i do, everytime i tried to create an object by requesting to

```
  http://localhost:5000/api/cart
```

I would get 401

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

Is there anything else I can do to make that post request successful ?

[image]